# PLSQL LS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I get this error while trying to run this procedure.I want to add the avg of notes for each student for every semester and year using a nested table.

Can anyone help me figure it out ?

```
Create or Replace type lista_medii is table of number;
Alter Table studenti Add medii lista_medii nested table medii store as value;

Create or replace procedure populare_medii
as
    lista_tmp lista_medii := lista_medii();
begin
    For v_student in (Select *from studenti) LOOP

         For an in 1 .. v_student.AN LOOP
             For medii_student in (select avg(valoare)from note join CURSURI on note.ID_CURS=CURSURI.ID where CURSURI.AN=1 and note.ID_STUDENT=29 group by cursuri.SEMESTRU) LOOP
                    lista_tmp.extend();
                    lista_tmp(lista_tmp.COUNT) := medii_student;
                end loop;
             update STUDENTI set STUDENTI.medii=lista_tmp where studenti.ID=v_student.id;
                lista_tmp.delete();
             end loop;
        end loop;
end populare_medii;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be like this:

```
For medii_student in (select avg(valoare) as avg_valoare from note join CURSURI on note.ID_CURS=CURSURI.ID where CURSURI.AN=1 and note.ID_STUDENT=29 group by cursuri.SEMESTRU) LOOP
      lista_tmp.extend();
      lista_tmp(lista_tmp.COUNT) := medii_student.avg_valoare ;
end loop;
```

Or better:

```
select avg(valoare) 
BULK COLLECT INTO lista_tmp
from note 
   join CURSURI on note.ID_CURS=CURSURI.ID 
where CURSURI.AN=1 
   and note.ID_STUDENT=29 
group by cursuri.SEMESTRU
```

Or even better:

```
update STUDENTI set STUDENTI.medii =
(select avg(valoare) 
    from note 
       join CURSURI on note.ID_CURS=CURSURI.ID 
    where CURSURI.AN=1 
       and note.ID_STUDENT=29 
    group by cursuri.SEMESTRU)
where studenti.ID=v_student.id;
```

Or even more better do it in one single UPDATE statement - try by yourself!